# Timer with visual alerts for Windows 7

Tags: gratis, windows-7, time-management

I'm looking for a **free** or open source lightweight **timer** compatible with Windows 7.

Essentially I'm looking for a pomodoro-type timer, but I don't want 30 minute intervals; I want to set my intervals. I'd like for it to **alert me somehow visually** that the time is up, even if it's running in the background.

Basically I want a program that will tell me to get up and stretch and/or rest my eyes every hour or x minutes. I'd like it to restart when I tell it that my break is done. Pausing would be nice, but not essential. I'd like it to be lightweight. I guess it could be a webapp. And I'd like it to **not** lock me out.

I tried [workrave](http://www.workrave.org/), but it doesn't alert me well enough. And google timer only has audible alerts while I often have the computer muted.

***Requirements***

1. Free
2. Visual Alerts on Windows 7
3. Capable of 1-hour intervals, even if it only uses fixed inherent schemes
4. Reset the interval when I tell it to
5. Pausing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use an open source timer called Hourglass. It has a great interface and is very lightweight. It can alert you visually or using audio alerts as well. It meets all of your requirements including,

1. Free - It's open source.
2. Visual Alerts on Windows 7 - Popups, flashing, audio alerts which can all be configured.
3. Capable of 1-hour intervals, even if it only uses fixed inherent schemes - it does basically *any* time frame you give it.
4. Reset the interval when I tell it to
5. Pausing

## [Hourglass](http://chris.dziemborowicz.com/apps/hourglass/) ([open source](https://github.com/Dziemborowicz/Hourglass))

> ### Advanced simplicity
>
> Hourglass is the most advanced simple countdown timer for Windows.
>   Just enter a time in just about any format, and hit Enter.
>
> - Pause and resume Start, stop, pause and resume your timers. Finally, an
>     app that can do everything your kitchen timer can.
> - Smart input Type a
>     duration like 5 minutes or a date and time like August 11 at 8 pm to
>     start your timer.
> - Beep, beep, beep Choose from three different
>     versions of the same beeping noise. Or use your own notification sound
>     instead.
> - Improved
>     interface Brighten up your device with the new color support. Or tell
>     apart multiple timers by assigning a title to each one.
> - Right-click
>     for more Set advanced options, start common timers, resume closed
>     timers, manage custom colors and sounds, and more… Absolutely free
> - Hourglass is absolutely free to use, free to share, and free to hack.
>     No ads. No in-app purchase. No nothing.
>
> [image: Hourglass Screenshots]

Comment: Just grabbed this it's basically perfect. Thanks!

Comment: ha! Wonderful - great find!